# Why am I receiving an error when trying to export a Workflow list to Excel in CRM?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-9, dynamics-crm

We recently installed Rollup 15 and post update, I receive an error message when I try and export any listing of Workflows to Excel.  In IE, I receive the generic 'An error has occured...' message but I snipped the below from a trace file:

```
MSCRM Error Report: 
Error: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.   
Error Message: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.   

Error Details: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.   Source File: Not available   Line Number: Not available   Request URL: http://crm/TheMaschhoffsInc/_grid/print/print_data.aspx   Stack   Trace Info: [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
    at Microsoft.Crm.Controls.ExportToExcelPage.ConfigurePage()
    at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Controls.AppUIPage.OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
    at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)   [HttpUnhandledException: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.]
    at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
    at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
    at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
    at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
    at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context)
    at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    at ASP.themaschhoffsinc__grid_print_print_data_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
    at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

---

Any ideas on what is happening?  I am using CRM 4.0 - rollup 15, IE9, Win 7

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen the thread in the Dynamics Forums about this problem http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-PH/crm/thread/db6bf988-b413-4015-ad07-1b54019e11c7

As first step I would recommend to install Rollup 18 (which is the latest rollup).

Comment: Unfortunately, RU 18 is too new for our CRM developer to install presently.  We were on RU 7 for the past year and just moved to RU 15.